# When vim-ing a folder, how do I make a new file?

Tags: command-line, vim

I looked around a bit and couldn't find anything on this, but here's the scenario:

- I vim a folder, to see what's up.
- I navigate to another folder via j/k/arrow keys/whatever and hit enter
- I realize I want to make a new file in this current folder I'm looking in
- ????

I know you can do stuff like :e path/filename, but if you do that then it will save in the initial directory you vim'd the first folder from. I guess you could :cd to the directory, but considering there are other commands available like x and D, I was wondering if there's a hidden one for new file or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netrw is the plugin for browsing filesystems that comes with Vim out of the box. That's what you use when navigating through folders.

Use `% name.of.file` to open a *new file* in the current directory displayed by netrw.

See `:help netrw` for more info.